# How to specify multiple jar files on the modulepath for java on the command line?

Tags: java, java-module, module-path

For the `java` command line tool, there is now the `--module-path` option as a replacement for the `--class-path` (or `-cp`) option.

With the classpath option, you can specify wildcards to include all jars in a given directory. E.g.:

```
java -cp "main.jar:lib/*" com.company.app.Main
```

Doing the same with the module path does not seem to work. Are wildcards possible there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--module-path` option expects a *list of directories* separated by `:` (at least on macOS and Linux).

From `java -help`:

```
--module-path <module path>...
              A : separated list of directories, each directory
              is a directory of modules.
```

So if there is a `lib` directory with all jar files, use something like this:

```
java --module-path "main.jar:lib" --module mymodule/com.company.app.Main
```